# Nginx tcp proxy route based on protocol just like Haproxy

Tags: nginx, proxy, haproxy

I have a issue with nginx. I wrote a custom backend with port 8888. And the 9999 port backend is a http server.

I want to route request to diff backends base on tls termination origin protocol in Nginx, just like Haproxy.

Https(after tls termination it's http) request route to httpBackend, in Haproxy I could use `use_backend ** if HTTP`, then request https://aa.aa it return webpage.

Other tls requests route to customBackend, in Haproxy I could use code `default_backend **`.

So how could I do the same things in Nginx just like Haproxy?

Thanks!

Nginx code:

```
stream {
        upstream custombackend{
                server 127.0.0.1:8888;
        }
        upstream httpbackend{
                server 127.0.0.1:9999;
        }
        server {
                listen 443 ssl;
                // only route to httpbackend..
                proxy_pass httpbackend;
                ssl_certificate /etc/cert/fullchain.cer;
                ssl_certificate_key /etc/cert/aa.aa.key;
        }
}
http{
    server {
        listen       9999;
        server_name  aa.aa;
        ......
}
```

Haproxy code:

```
defaults
    log global
    mode tcp

frontend tls-in
    bind *:443 tfo ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/aa.aa.pem
    tcp-request content accept if HTTP
    tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
    // which Nginx code could route request just like below ??
    use_backend httpback if HTTP
    default_backend customback

backend customback
    server server1 127.0.0.1:8888

backend httpback
    server server1 127.0.0.1:9999
```

Answer (score 0):

Well,I find a way using ngx_stream_js_module, But I dont think the performance could compare to Haproxy, so I would use haproxy instead.